# Doing sehri after 12 AM is acceptable or not?

Tags: ramadan

Consider Sehri time is before 4.30 AM in the morning. And, I'm doing it at around 1 AM.

Is that acceptable ?

P.S : I'm staying as a paying guest where none of my friends are muslims. And, I dont want to disturb them at early morning. If its for a day or two I can request them to adjust and ofcousre they will do that. But, as it is for whole month I am not able to request them for adjustment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sehri is not fard it is sunna. You can skip it if you want.

As for the time, it is not mentioned by the prophet an exact time for it so I think it is ok.

Sehri is just so that it will help you in the morning to fast.